# Derivatives and Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

[Mathway checking if integral equals to original function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQEWv.png)

Why is the integral not giving me the correct original function?

Comment: Perform long division. The derivative of a constant is zero

Comment: What would I perform long division on?

Comment: On what you circled in RED.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different example that underlines your issue. Both $\frac{x}{x+1}$ and $1-\frac{1}{x+1}$ are exactly the same. The second term is obtained from the first through long division. They both have the same derivative (!) So when the derivative is given as the function to integrate...you found one way and the software found the way. The difference is in the C

Comment: Oh ok , the long division making it in the format of the answer makes more sense. Thank you